# How to get http response using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to web programming.Previously I worked in java module.I want to get http response by hitting particular url.I am looking in w3c schools and I am trying still no result.please help me I want to full webpage source.

code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js">
</script>
<script>
var response = '';
$.ajax({ type: "GET",   
         url: "http://www.google.com",   
         async: false,
         success : function(text)
         {
             response = text;
         }
});

alert(response);
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="submit" />
<p>hello how are you </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can use the object data recieved after success of the ajax to retrive the url in response

Comment: The var `response` doesn't exist out the ajax call, you need to use it insice de `success` call event.

Comment: are you getting an alert with this code ?

Comment: I am not getting anything inside also

Comment: You browser has a JavaScript error console. Use it.

Comment: @peter when you pass this example at that time they are some problem so not call success function they go in error also call error same as success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

From the JQuery ajax method [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol.

Comment: if i change url also I am not getting any response

Comment: It has to be a path relative to the page on which the JavaScript code is running.

Comment: I have one website url which contains json response so that how can I get that json response.

Comment: Is that URL on the same domain as the JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can also add error callback and debug it what happening.

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET",   
     url: "http://www.google.com",   
     async: false,
     success : function(data, textStatus)
     {
         alert(data);
         alert(textStatus);
     },
     error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
     {
         alert(XMLHttpRequest);
         alert(textStatus);
         alert(errorThrown);
     }
```

});